# is it always faster to store multiple class calls in a variable?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, optimization, coding-style

If you have a method such as this:

```
float method(myClass foo)
{
    return foo.PrivateVar() + foo.PrivateVar();
}
```

is it always faster/better to do this instead?:

```
float method(myClass foo)
{
    float temp = foo.PrivateVar();
    return temp + temp;
}
```

I know you're not supposed to put a call like `foo.PrivateVar()` in a for loop for example, because it evaluates it many times when you actually only need to use the value once (in some cases.

```
for (int i = 0; i < foo.PrivateInt(); i++)
{
    //iterate through stuff with 'i'
}
```

from this I made the assumption to change code like the first example to that in the second, but then I've been told by people to not try to be smarter than the compiler! and that it could very well inline the calls.

I don't want to profile anything, I just want a few simple rules for good practice on this. I'm writing a demo for a job application and I don't want anyone to look at the code and see some rookie mistake.

Comment: Can we assume the function has no side-effects? Otherwise this is a meaningless comparison.

Comment: You'll get people complaining either way; there is no magic bullet. e.g. *I* would advise you not to make that `for` loop optimization a *habit*, because it means you're likely to mess up and write wrong code in a situation where the value returned by `PrivateInt()` changes during the course of the loop. IMO, the "right" thing to do is to learn how to write correct, readable code, and separately learn how and when to optimize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That completely depends on what `PrivateVar()` is doing and where it's defined etc. If the compiler has access to the code in `PrivateVar()` and can guarantee that there are no side effects by calling the function it can do CSE which is basically what you've done in your second code example.

Exactly the same is true for your for loop. So if you want to be sure it's only evaluated once because it's a hugely expensive function (which also means that guaranteeing no side-effects get's tricky even if there aren't any) write it explicitly.

If `PrivateVar()` is just a getter, write the clearer code - even if the compiler may not do CSE the performance difference won't matter in 99.9999% of all cases.

Edit: CSE stands for [Common Subexpression eliminiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) and does exactly what it stands for ;) The wiki page shows an example for a simple multiplication, but we can do this for larger code constructs just as well, like for example a function call.

In all cases we have to guarantee that only evaluating the code once doesn't change the semantics, i.e. doing CSE for this code:

```
a = b++ * c + g;
d = b++ * c * d;
```

and changing it to:

```
tmp = b++ * c;
a = tmp + g;
d = tmp * d;
```

would obviously be illegal (for function calls this is obviously a bit more complex, but it's the same principle).

Comment: @Cicada, Did you know that 87% of all statistics are just made up?

Comment: so basically do the second one UNLESS it's just a simple getter? so are you also saying that it's OK to put a getter in a for loop? no one would judge me for it? because one stack-overflower referred to that particular aspect of my code as a 'no-no'.

Comment: Can you define what CSE is for those of us who don't write compilers for a living?

Comment: @SirYakalot, people on the internet complain about a lot of things. Most here would agree to make it clear first, then worry about performance only when it becomes a problem. See http://xkcd.com/386/

Comment: @SirYakalot The thing I hope you'd take away is: Write the clearest possible code except if you know that it's THE performance critical part of your application in which case you may want to do it explicitly. Personally I've written your for loop example often enough and have seen it used by lots of great coders. I really wouldn't worry about it. The 99.99% above may be a slight exaggeration but the vast majority of code you write isn't performance critical but people will still have to read and understand it.

Comment: @Mark Yeah silly me for using acronyms without expanding them - I don't think it's important what exactly it is in this but I'll fix it with a link and a bit longer explanation than "basically what you've done in your second code example".